# SQL grouping by parent child

Tags: sql

If I had this structure with the columns:

Primary_Key, Name, Parent_Primary_ID, DISPLAY_ORDER

```
1 Event NULL 1

2 News NULL 2

3 Event_List 1 1

4 Event_Detail 1 2

5 News_List 2 1

6 News_Details 2 2
```

how would you return data like:

```
1 Event

3 Event_List

4 Event_Detail

2 News

5 News_List

6 News_Detail
```

Thanks
Rob

Comment: What do you think you are grouping?

Comment: Seems like a complicated way to try and produce the list.  Adding a category column (Event, News) would be a way to produce simpler queries.

Comment: Seems like some indentation could go a long way...Essentially he's trying to "group" by the parent/child relationships, then order by name of the path. Martin's solution solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If SQL Server 2005+

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE 
(Primary_Key INT PRIMARY KEY,
 Name VARCHAR(100), 
 Parent_Primary_ID INT NULL,
 DISPLAY_ORDER INT)


INSERT INTO @YourTable
SELECT 1,'Event',NULL,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'News',NULL,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Event_List',1,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'Event_Detail',1,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'News_List',2,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'News_Details',2,2;

WITH Hierarchy
     AS (SELECT *,
                path = CAST(DISPLAY_ORDER AS VARCHAR(100))
         FROM   @YourTable
         WHERE  Parent_Primary_ID IS NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT y.Primary_Key,
                y.Name,
                y.Parent_Primary_ID,
                y.DISPLAY_ORDER,
                CAST(path + '.' + CAST(y.DISPLAY_ORDER AS VARCHAR) AS VARCHAR(100))
         FROM   @YourTable y
                JOIN Hierarchy h
                  ON h.Primary_Key = y.Parent_Primary_ID)
SELECT Primary_Key,
       Name
FROM   Hierarchy
ORDER  BY path
```

Comment: +1, for including the temp table def.  Love being able to copy/paste/test an answer.  Also returns the right results in the right order.

Comment: Any chance you could explain in English how the heck ordering is being done?

Answer (score 1):

Try (asumming standardish sql is supported)

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE 
(Primary_Key INT PRIMARY KEY,
 Name VARCHAR(100), 
 Parent_Primary_ID INT NULL,
 DISPLAY_ORDER INT)


INSERT INTO @YourTable
SELECT 1,'Event',NULL,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'News',NULL,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Event_List',1,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'Event_Detail',1,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'News_List',2,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'News_Details',2,2;

select
    primary_key = t1.primary_key,
    name = t1.name
from
    @YourTable t1
    left join @YourTable t2 on t1.parent_primary_id = t2.Primary_Key
order by
    coalesce(t2.DISPLAY_ORDER,t1.DISPLAY_ORDER,0),
    case    
        when t2.Primary_Key is null then 0
        else t1.DISPLAY_ORDER
    end
```

Comment: I ran this in SQL Server.  It is unnecessarily complex and doesn't appear to work.  Query I tested with is below, let me know if I did something wrong.

Comment: WITH temp as
(
  SELECT 1 as Primary_Key, 'Event' as Name, null Parent_Primary_ID, 1 as Display_Order
  UNION 
  SELECT 2, 'News', null, 2
  UNION
  SELECT 3, 'Event_List', 1, 1
  UNION
 SELECT 4, 'Event_Detail', 1, 2
 UNION
 SELECT 5,'News_List', 2, 1
 UNION
 SELECT 6,'News_Details', 2, 2

)
select
    primary_key = coalesce(t2.primary_key,t1.primary_key),
    name = coalesce(t2.name,t1.name)
from
    temp t1
    left join temp t2 on t1.primary_key = t2.parent_primary_id
order by
    t1.Display_Order,
    coalesce(t2.Display_Order,0)

Comment: Sorry -was going too fast after messing up the original post! Amended now. My way doesn't require going through a temp table - its just returns the data in the correct order. Just run it as you see it above

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any grouping in your results.  Unless you are trying to do something you aren't telling us I would use the query below:

```
SELECT Primary_Key, Name FROM YourTable
```

I don't see how you are ordering those results so I didn't try to order them.